# Unity Always move object forward

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, touch

I have the ability to both move and rotate my camera. The rotation of my code works by rotating the parent object of my camera and my movement code also moves my parent object.

However, when I rotate the parent object, my movement code goes awry. At the moment, if I use two fingers to and swipe up, I want my camera to always move forward based on where it is looking. Similar for when I move down, left and right. I would like my camera to move backwards, left and right respectively.

At the moment, when I first start my app, everything works fine. But then when I rotate my parent object 90 degrees to the right, when I swipe up, my camera moves to the left. As I am unsure how to offset this rotation from my forward direction.

These are my two methods:

```
void MoveCamera ()
{

    Vector2 delta = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

    // invert option is if I want to manually change the direction everything moves
    // move fingers left to go right etc
    float positonX = delta.x * sensitivityX * Time.deltaTime;
    positonX = invertX ? positonX : positonX * -1;

    float positionY = delta.y * sensitivityY * Time.deltaTime;
    positionY = invertY ? positionY : positionY * -1;

    transform.parent.position += new Vector3(positonX, 0, positionY);
}

Vector2 CameraOrbit ()
{

    Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;

    //vertical movement is corresponded to rotation in x-axis
    orbitSpeedX = -touchDeltaPosition.y * rotXSpeedModifier;

    //horizontal movement is corresponded to rotation in y-axis
    orbitSpeedY = touchDeltaPosition.x * rotYSpeedModifier;

    //get the current rotation
    float x = transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.x;
    float y = transform.parent.rotation.eulerAngles.y;

    //make sure x is between -180 to 180 so we can clamp it propery later
    if (x > 180)
    {
        x -= 360;
    }

    //y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

    //calculate the x and y rotation
    Quaternion rotationY = Quaternion.Euler (0, y, 0) * Quaternion.Euler (0, orbitSpeedY, 0);
    Quaternion rotationX = Quaternion.Euler (Mathf.Clamp (x + orbitSpeedX, minRotX, maxRotX), 0, 0);

    //apply the rotation
    transform.parent.rotation = rotationY * rotationX;
    orbitSpeedX *= (1 - Time.deltaTime * 12);
    orbitSpeedY *= (1 - Time.deltaTime * 3);

    return touchDeltaPosition;
}
```

Before I had this code, I was moving my camera using `transform.Translate` and this worked and I could move forward no matter my rotation. But, the cameras Y position would move when I need that to stay at what ever height it is when I start to move. This would make it look like it was zoom out the more forward I pushed.

Comment: What do you mean you want it to move forward? as in walking forward/zooming ? or sliding upwards with your fingers? what do you mean by goes awry? what is `invertX` / `invertY` ?

Comment: I'll edit my question so I don't leave too much of a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having the problem of constantly moving in one direction without considering the direction you are facing?

I'm not exactly sure how to fix your problem, but here's an example from what I use:

Let's say I'm making a first person shooter game for a computer. Here is the code I would use for the movement:

Vector3 position = transform.position + new Vector3 (Input.getAxis("some1"), Input.getAxis("some2"), 0) * transform.direction;
transform.position = position.

This calculates the movement based on the direction.
If it still doesn't work, then comment again and I will be glad to help!

Comment: I get the following error Operator `*' cannot be applied to operands of type `float' and `UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Comment: @N0xus Hmm. I will post the big idea I generally use any maybe you can try to use it in your program some how?